# how to compare db date with current date in bootstrap?

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4

i have bootstrap laravel page where i want to compare db date with curent date if it is less then 1 day i want to add class

```
 @elseif( ($order->order_date, strtotime('now - 1day')) < date('yy-m-d') )
                    <tr class="delivery-missed">
                    @else
                    <tr>
```

i know this query is wrong what is the write way?
or i should use java script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Carbon`.

Doing something like this:

```
@php
 $order_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($order->order_date);
 $now = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
@endphp
 <tr class="{{ $order_date->diff($now)->days < 1 ? 'delivery-missed' : '' }}">
```